# Is there any reason not to buy 2x11 GRX shifters for a 1x setup if I don't plan on adding a dropper post?

Tags: shimano

I plan to buy a Shimano GRX 1x11 groupset. My understanding is that Shimano offer two left-hand shifters:

- 2-speed for 2x11 setups
- Dropper-post lever for 1x11 setups with a dropper post

I do not plan to run a dropper post in the future, but I might switch to 2x11 if I decide that 1x11 does not offer enough gears.

It seems more sensible then to buy 2x11 shifters and simply not connect the shifting cable on the 2-speed lever to anything. If I choose to move to 2x11 speed then I do not need to buy any new shifters.

Is there any reason not to do this?

Comment: Aside from addition cost?

Answer (score 1):

None that I can think of. It will be much easier to use the 2x shifter, rather than swapping out the dropper lever for a shifter later down the road.